# Can one show that $\sum_{k=10}^{50} a_k \cos(k \theta)$ has at least four zeroes on $[0,2\pi]$ for $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, fourier-series

This is a complex analysis puzzle that seems tricky.

How can one show that for $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sum_{k=10}^{50} a_k \cos(k \theta)$ has at least four zeroes on $[0,2\pi]$?
A hint is to consider the function $g(z) = \sum_{k=10}^{50} a_k z^k$ on the unit disk, whose real part on the unit circle coincides with the sum above.

The bounds $10 \to 50$ are probably overkill. What's the general trick to analyze this kind of questions?

ANSWERED IN COMMENTS:
The point is that the winding number of the function around the unit circle is at least $20\pi$. Given a curve surrounding a domain $D$, the total change in the argument of any function $f(z)$ around equals (number of zeroes in $D$) - (number of poles in $D$). For us, our $g(z)$ has an order 10 zero at the origin and no poles for this polynomial, the winding number will be at least 10, which means that the real part of $g(z)$ hits zero at least 20 times.

Comment: You can consider the winding number as we traverse the unit circle. That's be related to the number of roots

Comment: The point is that the complex function in cause has a zero of order $10$ at the origin, which means that on the unit circle it must turn a bunch of times (hence its argument will change a lot) so its real part will have a bunch of zeroes; try and formalize this yourself as it's good exercise (by cauchy the normalized integral of $f'/f$ on the unit circle is at least $10$ so the argument of $f$ changes by at least $20 \pi$)

Comment: How would that work? Clearly the winding number at infinity will be 50 and the winding number around zero will be 10. But I can't see how to argue it should be at least 4 on the unit circle. In principle, there could be a lot of zeroes inside the unit disk that make the winding number small on the unit circle.

Comment: Oh I see, only poles can reduce the winding number. Any other zeroes will just increase the winding number on the unit circle. So the case of ten zeroes will be in the case that the only roots inside the unit disk are at the origin.

Comment: Yes that's right and the summation to $50$ is indeed a bit of a red herring as surmised in the post